# Change the content of a div based on selection from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is there a simple way, using JavaScript, to dynamically show/hide content in a `<div>` based on the users selection from a drop down menu? For example, if a user selects `option 1` then I would like `<div>` 1 to be displayed and all other `<div>`s to be hidden.

EDIT: Example `HTML` Setup

```html
<select>
<option> Option 1</option>
<option> Option 2</option>
<option> Option 3</option>
<select>

<div id="content_1" style="display:hidden;">Content 1<div>
<div id="content_2" style="display:hidden;">Content 2<div>
<div id="content_3" style="display:hidden;">Content 3<div>
```

Comment: Yes there is. If you show what you've got so far, you might get some help. More sensible would be to learn the rudiments of Javascript and the DOM and learn to write it yourself, rather than relying on cut-and-paste code.

Comment: Hmm, well Im really just looking for a technique. If you read my question, I don't think I asked for a cut/paste piece of code, just a method.

Comment: The method is to create a listener on the dropdown menu for the `change` event, and then change the `display` style property for each of the `div` elements accordingly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/1/) with an example of showing/hiding div's via a select.

HTML:

```
<div id="option1" class="group">asdf</div>
<div id="option2" class="group">kljh</div>
<div id="option3" class="group">zxcv</div>
<div id="option4" class="group">qwerty</div>
<select id="selectMe">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.group').hide();
  $('#option1').show();
  $('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
  })
});
```

Comment: the jsfiddle doesn't work!
returns 404. BTW jquary requires any compiler?

Answer (score 29):

The accepted answer has a couple of shortcomings:

- Don't target IDs in your JavaScript code. Use classes and data attributes to [avoid repeating your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
- It is good practice to hide with CSS on load rather than with JavaScript—to support non-JavaScript users, and prevent a show-hide flicker on load.

Considering the above, your options could even have different values, but toggle the same class:

```
<select class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
  <option value="orange" data-show=".citrus">Orange</option>
  <option value="lemon" data-show=".citrus">Lemon</option>
  <option value="apple" data-show=".pome">Apple</option>
  <option value="pear" data-show=".pome">Pear</option>
</select>

<div class="my-info-1">
  <div class="citrus hide">Citrus is...</div>
  <div class="pome hide">A pome is...</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.div-toggle', function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
  $(target).children().addClass('hide');
  $(show).removeClass('hide');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div-toggle').trigger('change');
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Here's [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLBvx/252/) to see it in action.

Comment: Any reason why my one won't seem to work? http://jsfiddle.net/fuvxkzkd/ - Strangely enough, the version running on my local site, does seem to work partially, but it doesn't add the 'hide' class to option elements if another is selected, so it just adds to the list of lines that's displayed

Comment: @Lee If you check your JavaScript console, you will see `$ is not defined` which means jQuery has not been loaded on your fiddle. On JSFiddle, add `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js` to External Resources on the left.

Comment: Ah. Wow I feel stupid, I thought JSfiddle automatically included it. Okay that'll be fine then. I managed to get my local version working fine too by the way, thanks.

Answer (score 22):

With zero jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <style>
.inv {
    display: none;
}
    </style>
    <body>
        <select id="target">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="content_1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="content_2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="content_3">Option 3</option>
        <select>

        <div id="content_1" class="inv">Content 1</div>
        <div id="content_2" class="inv">Content 2</div>
        <div id="content_3" class="inv">Content 3</div>
        
        <script>
            document
                .getElementById('target')
                .addEventListener('change', function () {
                    'use strict';
                    var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
                        target = document.getElementById(this.value);
                    if (vis !== null) {
                        vis.className = 'inv';
                    }
                    if (target !== null ) {
                        target.className = 'vis';
                    }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Codepen

```js
document
  .getElementById('target')
  .addEventListener('change', function () {
    'use strict';
    var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
      target = document.getElementById(this.value);
    if (vis !== null) {
      vis.className = 'inv';
    }
    if (target !== null ) {
      target.className = 'vis';
    }
});
```

```css
.inv {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="target">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="content_1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="content_2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="content_3">Option 3</option>
        <select>

        <div id="content_1" class="inv">Content 1</div>
        <div id="content_2" class="inv">Content 2</div>
        <div id="content_3" class="inv">Content 3</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do i make this work if i have to select two drop down to make the text change

Answer (score 8):

Meh too slow. Here's my example anyway :)
http://jsfiddle.net/cqDES/

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            $('div:not(#div' + val + ')').slideUp();
            $('#div' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('div').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Might want to hide the elements on load in your fiddle.

Comment: @rybo111 Yeah I could, but then if you select the empty option it shows them all again so it could be a feature.

Comment: The OP hid them on load in his question, so that was the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a coder, but you could save a few lines:

```
<div>
            <select onchange="if(selectedIndex!=0)document.getElementById('less_is_more').innerHTML=options[selectedIndex].value;">
                <option value="">hire me for real estate</option>
                <option value="me!!!">Who is a good Broker? </option>
                <option value="yes!!!">Can I buy a house with no down payment</option>
                <option value="send me a note!">Get my contact info?</option>
            </select>
        </div>

<div id="less_is_more"></div>
```

Here is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Gloak/0cndazt6/2/).

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to perform your task, but the most elegant are, I believe, using css.
Here are basic steps

1. Listening option selection event, biding adding/removing some class to container action, which contains all divs you are interested in (for example, body)
2. Adding styles for hiding all divs except one.
3. Well done, sir.

This works pretty well if there a few divs, since more elements you want to toggle, more css rules should be written. Here is more general solution, binding action, base on following steps:
  1. find all elements using some selector (usually it looks like '.menu-container .menu-item')
  2. find one of found elements, which is current visible, hide it
  3. make visible another element, the one you desire to be visible under new circumstances.

javascript it a rather timtoady language )