# Div Display Hide on Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi There _ I'm a Newbie to all of this and really struggling with a dropdown menu that displays a div on loading but then hides the div and replaces with another on selection from a dropdown. I've spent hours trying to get this right and looked at a number of options. The closest I've got is a response to [an earlier question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164507/change-the-content-of-a-div-based-on-selection-from-drop-down-menu). I've settled on [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849350/6515543).

I've adapted it slightly as don't want "Select...".

Script remains the same, as does the CSS. Here is the HTML which I've adapted:

```
<select id="target">
                    <option value="content_1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="content_2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="content_3">Option 3</option>
                </select>

                <div id="content_1" class="inv" style="width:250px; margin-left:-10px; height:420px">Content 1</div>
                <div id="content_2" class="inv" style="width:250px; margin-left:-10px; height:420px">Content 2</div>
                <div id="content_3" class="inv" style="width:250px; margin-left:-10px; height:420px">Content 3</div>
```

and just in case here's the script:

```
<script>
    document
        .getElementById('target')
        .addEventListener('change', function() {
            'use strict';
            var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
                target = document.getElementById(this.value);
            if (vis !== null) {
                vis.className = 'inv';
            }
            if (target !== null) {
                target.className = 'vis';
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to put window.onload=function(){ at the beginning of the script

Answer (score 0):

You may add your code at the end of the body or you can use the [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document
  .getElementById('target')
  .addEventListener('change', function() {
    'use strict';
    var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
        target = document.getElementById(this.value);
    if (vis !== null) {
      vis.className = 'inv';
    }
    if (target !== null) {
      target.className = 'vis';
    }
  });
  
  // send change event to element to select the first div...
  var event = new Event('change');
   document.getElementById('target').dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```css
.inv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="target">
    <option value="content_1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="content_2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="content_3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div id="content_1" class="inv" style="width:250px; margin-left:-10px; height:420px">Content 1</div>
<div id="content_2" class="inv" style="width:250px; margin-left:-10px; height:420px">Content 2</div>
<div id="content_3" class="inv" style="width:250px; margin-left:-10px; height:420px">Content 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... So how do I get the Content 1 div to show on load, be replaced by Content 2 if option 2 is selected and Content 3 if option 3 selected etc. etc? Sounds like I'm nearly there but missing something really straight forward :)

Comment: @StuartThompson you may trigger an change event like in my updated snippet.

Comment: at the moment content 1 doesn't show on load. Thx again

Comment: @StuartThompson See to the snippet: I updated it: var event = new Event('change');document.getElementById('target').dispatchEvent(event);  Bye