# PHP form that loads page based on option clicked from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dropdown list in which i have 9 options lets say (A-I). the A and B option on being clicked opens another dropdown list with a few elements whereas the remaining options should open up a new page lets say c_page.php for c, d_page.php for D and so on.

Whereas for option A and B it should open a another dropdown list (as discussed above) on which an option is chosen and then on being clicked on Next a_page.php and b_page.php.

Next button should open the desired page in every case.

I have found this similar code on stackoverflow only but it displays error: Notice: Undefined index: selectedPage

here's the code:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="theForm" id="theForm">
<select form="theForm" name="selectedPage">
  <option value="page_1">Page 1</option>
  <option value="page_2">Page 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Load page" />
</form>
<?php
$requested_page = $_POST['selectedPage'];

switch($requested_page) {
  case "page_1":
    header("Location: page_1.php");
  break;
  case "page_2":
    header("Location: page_2.php");
  break;
  default :
  echo "No page was selected";
  break;
}
?>
```

Correct this example too and also help me in developing my code.

Comment: You have to use jquery to do this or submit the form, process the value and return a page.

Comment: Changing the page without submitting and reloading requires Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164507/change-the-content-of-a-div-based-on-selection-from-drop-down-menu

Comment: @VikingBlooded You definitely don't have to use jQuery. Please don't misinform other people.

Comment: @kajetons have to might be incorrect, but in this case it's what it does and does it well.

Comment: @VikingBlooded Sure, it handles AJAX pretty well, but it's definitely an overkill for something this simple. I also see no point in recommending a library considering the OP lacks even a basic knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: Please at least try to do something yourself. We're not here to do your homework.