# Change the content of a div based on selection from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of links such as:

```
<li><a href="#">Alabama</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Alaska</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Arizona</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Arkansas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">California</a></li>
```

I have a div section(an article) that I want to update dynamically as a selection is made from the list.

```
<div>Select a state from the list</div>
```

**Desired outcome**: Selecting Alabama from the list displays in the main div a list of counties in Alabama.

**Current outcome**: Selecting Alabama from the list does not update the main div.

How can I best accomplish this? JavaScript? JQuery? JSFiddle?

I am looking for something maybe similar to this: [Change the content of a div based on selection from dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164507/change-the-content-of-a-div-based-on-selection-from-drop-down-menu)

But I had no luck getting that to work with a list.

Comment: can you post the code that you have tried? Did you try that example that you posted?

Comment: Yeah, I gave the answer by rybo111 a try, but had a hard time converting it to work with a list selection. Particularly the 3rd line in his JQuery about option:selected. I am not familiar with JQuery.

Comment: Were you getting any errors / properly incorporating jQuery into your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an event listener to listen to clicks on the unordered list element.

```js
var states = document.getElementById('states');
var main = document.getElementById('main');

states.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't navigate to <a> tag href
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    main.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="states">
  <li><a href="#">Alabama</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Alaska</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Arizona</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Arkansas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">California</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="main">Main</div>
```

Note that we can add a single [click event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the parent of all the list items and then we check to make sure the click was on an [A](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag by comparing the [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName). Then we can copy the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) from the clicked element to the main element.

Comment: This looks like it might work. Can you provide some more input on  if (e.target.tagName === 'A')?

Comment: Can't quite get this to work. not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @levijoraan I explained below the code snippet. Does "Run code snippet" work in your browser?

Comment: Yep, your example works well. I got it to work with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ul id="list">
<li><a href="#">Alabama</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Alaska</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Arizona</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Arkansas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">California</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="selection"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#list a').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#selection').text($(this).text());
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many different ways to do this and dependent on what the deeper level contents are will determine best method.

If it is an external html page you could so something like

html

```
<div id="div2"><div>
```

jquery

```
 $('#div1').select(),
 $('#div2').load("statesName.html");
```