# Add a child to a parent using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im working on a video selection using JS, and I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849497) which helped me out. The problem is

1. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849497) is nearly 7 years old
2. Im only able to test on chrome, but I get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: video.appendChild is not a function`
   This is the snippet of js/html of where the error is coming from.

```js
var video = document.getElementsByClassName("player");
var source = document.createElement("source");

source.setAttribute("src", "../shows/2020.mp4");


video.appendChild(source);
video.play();

$(document).on("change", "vid-select", function() {
  var show = $("option:selected", this).data("show")
  source.setAttribute("src", "../shows/" + show + ".mp4")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="past-player">
  <select class="vid-select" data-target= ".past-player .player">
    <option data-show: "2020">2020</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
  </select>
  <video class="player"></video>
</div>
```

I just want to know what is going wrong with the `video` var and why it cant have a child added to it to show the video.

I had originally tried `getElementById` with the `<video id="player">` on the first line of js, but this returned `null`.

EDIT: I have also tried `querySelector` and still recieved `null`

Comment: All attributes, and their values, are assigned using `=` never with `:` (unless you’re using a templating or scripting language I’m unfamiliar with). When is your JavaScript running, do the elements on the page exist when the JavaScript runs?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica The OP is not assigning anything with `:`. The only `:` I see in the code is to reference the `selected` CSS pseudo-class.

Comment: @Scott: but `<option data-show: "2020">` and `<select class="vid-select" data-target: ".past-player .player">`?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica that is not part of my issue at the moment, though I will bear that in mind!

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Ah, my mistake! I didn't see that one. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only interested (it seems) in working with the first `video` element, query for it with `.querySelector()` because `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a "live" node list (which is a collection) and node lists (collections) don't have an `.appendChild` method like individual elements do.

And, in your HTML you have `data-target:` and `data-show:`, which should be: `data-target=` and `data-show=`

And, you probably want to have your code run when the `select` value is changed not when the `document` is changed.

And, you really don't need `data-show` as `option` elements have their own `value` attribute, which is for exactly what you are doing here.

Also, [don't use `.getElementsByClassName()` even when you do want a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474), use `.querySelectorAll()` for that.

Lastly, make sure your `script` is located just prior to the closing `body` tag so that by the time it is encountered, all the HTML will have been parsed into memory and your queries will find the appropriate elements.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="past-player">
    <select class="vid-select" data-target=".past-player .player">
      <option value = "2020">2020</option>
      <option value = "2021">1</option>
      <option value = "2022">2</option>
      <option value = "2023">3</option>
      <option value = "2024">4</option>
      <option value = "2025">5</option>
      <option value = "2026">6</option>
      <option value = "2027">7</option>
    </select>
    <video class="player"></video>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script>
    var video = document.querySelector(".player");
    var source = document.createElement("source");

    source.src = "../shows/2020.mp4";

    video.appendChild(source);
    video.play();

    // Just access the select and set up an event on it
    $("select.vid-select").on("change", function() {
      var show = $("option:selected", this).val();
      source.src = "../shows/" + show + ".mp4";
      
      console.log(source.src); // Just for testing
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `querySelector` returns null still!

Comment: @LegacyCoding See my last edit about the location of your `script`.

Comment: jeez... i forgot that the positioning matters XD. Thank you!

Comment: Im going to cry myself to sleep once I fix the other half of the code XD

Comment: @LegacyCoding You're welcome. See my most recent edit as I've added more useful info.

Comment: Thanks for that, I seem to be having a JQuery issue now but other than that im sorted, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

getElementsByClassName returns an html collection, that is like an array, so you can use `video[0].appendChild(source);`, or get the element with `querySelector`

Comment: “*I had originally tried getElementById with the <video id="player"> on the first line of js, but this returned null.*”

Comment: Move the script tag down on the html, maybe it's loading before the video element that you want to get.